# Python DictWriter writing UTF-8 encoded CSV files

Tags: python, unicode, csv, utf-8

1. I have a list of dictionaries containing unicode strings.
2. `csv.DictWriter` can write a list of dictionaries into a CSV file.
3. I want the CSV file to be encoded in UTF8.
4. The `csv` module cannot handle converting unicode strings into UTF8.
5. The `csv` module documentation has an example for converting everything to UTF8:

   ```
   def utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data):
       for line in unicode_csv_data:
           yield line.encode('utf-8')
   ```
6. It also has a `UnicodeWriter` class.

But... how do I make `DictWriter` work with these?  Wouldn't they have to inject themselves in the middle of it, to catch the disassembled dictionaries and encode them before it writes them to the file?  I don't get it.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

**UPDATE**: The 3rd party [unicodecsv](https://pypi.org/project/unicodecsv/) module implements this 7-year old answer for you.  Example below this code.  There's also a Python 3 solution that doesn't required a 3rd party module.

**Original Python 2 Answer**

If using Python 2.7 or later, use a dict comprehension to remap the dictionary to utf-8 before passing to DictWriter:

```
# coding: utf-8
import csv
D = {'name':u'马克','pinyin':u'mǎkè'}
f = open('out.csv','wb')
f.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8')) # BOM (optional...Excel needs it to open UTF-8 file properly)
w = csv.DictWriter(f,sorted(D.keys()))
w.writeheader()
w.writerow({k:v.encode('utf8') for k,v in D.items()})
f.close()
```

You can use this idea to update UnicodeWriter to DictUnicodeWriter:

```
# coding: utf-8
import csv
import cStringIO
import codecs

class DictUnicodeWriter(object):

    def __init__(self, f, fieldnames, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.DictWriter(self.queue, fieldnames, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, D):
        self.writer.writerow({k:v.encode("utf-8") for k,v in D.items()})
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for D in rows:
            self.writerow(D)

    def writeheader(self):
        self.writer.writeheader()

D1 = {'name':u'马克','pinyin':u'Mǎkè'}
D2 = {'name':u'美国','pinyin':u'Měiguó'}
f = open('out.csv','wb')
f.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8')) # BOM (optional...Excel needs it to open UTF-8 file properly)
w = DictUnicodeWriter(f,sorted(D.keys()))
w.writeheader()
w.writerows([D1,D2])
f.close()
```

**Python 2 [unicodecsv](https://pypi.org/project/unicodecsv/) Example:**

```
# coding: utf-8
import unicodecsv as csv

D = {u'name':u'马克',u'pinyin':u'mǎkè'}

with open('out.csv','wb') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=sorted(D.keys()),encoding='utf-8-sig')
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(D)
```

**Python 3:**

Additionally, Python 3's built-in csv module supports Unicode natively:

```
# coding: utf-8
import csv

D = {u'name':u'马克',u'pinyin':u'mǎkè'}

# Use newline='' instead of 'wb' in Python 3.
with open('out.csv','w',encoding='utf-8-sig',newline='') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=sorted(D.keys()))
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(D)
```

Comment: I thought downgrading to Python(x, y) 2.6.6.0 would make things easier. :)

Comment: @endolith: You could use `dict((k, v.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(v, unicode) else v) for k, v in D.iteritems())` instead of dict comprehension on Python 2.6.

Comment: If `v` is not Unicode, and not UTF8 encoded, you now have a mess, though.

Comment: This class worked beautifully for me writing data from an API with JSON output. However, some of the incoming data was parsed as floats, so I'd get exceptions about float not having the method `encode()`. To fix this, I simply wrapped `v` with the `unicode()` (_not_ `str()`!) constructor in `writerow()`: `self.writer.writerow({k:unicode(v).encode("utf-8") for k,v in D.items()})`. This should fix what @Mark Tolonen mentions.

Comment: You deserve going to heaven after this!

Comment: @leonwu This is a 7-year old answer, but yes `unicodecsv` (and Python 3) are better answers now.  Updated...

Answer (score 41):

There is a simple workaround using the wonderful [UnicodeCSV](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.14.1) module. After having it, just change the line

```
import csv
```

to

```
import unicodecsv as csv
```

And it automagically begins playing nice with UTF-8.

**Note:** Switching to Python 3 will also rid you of this problem (thanks [jamescampbell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1215344/jamescampbell) for the tip). And it's something one should do anyway.

Comment: omfg finally  - what a nightmare this has been until this

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - so simple and works like a charm

Comment: You no longer need to do this in Python 3.x

Comment: You're absolutely right, updated my answer to include this detail.

Comment: Python 3 still doesn't take care of the utf8 bom.

Comment: I'm using Python 3 and still got a unicode error, trying this solution got rid of the unicode error, but gave me 'TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes'

Comment: @Jonathan I recently updated my answer with unicodecsv and Python 3 examples.  These an encoding that hangles the UTF-8 signature.

Comment: @Maitiu See my updated answer for a Python 3 example.  Python 3 strings are natively Unicode so you don't open the file in binary mode.

Answer (score 15):

You can convert the values to UTF-8 on the fly as you pass the dict to `DictWriter.writerow()`. For example:

```
import csv

rows = [
    {'name': u'Anton\xedn Dvo\u0159\xe1k','country': u'\u010cesko'},
    {'name': u'Bj\xf6rk Gu\xf0mundsd\xf3ttir', 'country': u'\xcdsland'},
    {'name': u'S\xf8ren Kierkeg\xe5rd', 'country': u'Danmark'}
    ]

# implement this wrapper on 2.6 or lower if you need to output a header
class DictWriterEx(csv.DictWriter):
    def writeheader(self):
        header = dict(zip(self.fieldnames, self.fieldnames))
        self.writerow(header)

out = open('foo.csv', 'wb')
writer = DictWriterEx(out, fieldnames=['name','country'])
# DictWriter.writeheader() was added in 2.7 (use class above for <= 2.6)
writer.writeheader()
for row in rows:
    writer.writerow(dict((k, v.encode('utf-8')) for k, v in row.iteritems()))
out.close()
```

Output **foo.csv**:

```
name,country
Antonín Dvořák,Česko
Björk Guðmundsdóttir,Ísland
Søren Kierkegård,Danmark
```

Comment: Nice one. I liked the implementation of one liner writerow func.

Comment: `writer.writerow(dict((k, v.encode('utf-8') if type(v) is unicode else v) for k, v in row.iteritems()))`

encode only for unicode characters. because int/list don't have unicode attribute.

Answer (score 6):

You can use some proxy class to encode dict values as needed, like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import csv
d = {'a':123,'b':456, 'c':u'Non-ASCII: проверка'}

class DictUnicodeProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = d
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.d.__iter__()
    def get(self, item, default=None):
        i = self.d.get(item, default)
        if isinstance(i, unicode):
            return i.encode('utf-8')
        return i

with open('some.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, ['a', 'b', 'c'])
    writer.writerow(DictUnicodeProxy(d))
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `csv.writer` with your content, the idea is to pass the content through `utf_8_encoder` as it would give you the (utf-8) encoded content.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is a bit different. While all solutions above are focusing on having unicode compatible dict, my solutions makes DictWriter compatible with unicode. This approach is even suggested in python docs ([1](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html?highlight=dictreader#examples)).

Classes UTF8Recoder, UnicodeReader, UnicodeWriter are taken from python docs. UnicodeWriter->writerow was changed a little bit too.

Use it as regular DictWriter/DictReader.

Here is the code:

```python
import csv, codecs, cStringIO

class UTF8Recoder:
    """
    Iterator that reads an encoded stream and reencodes the input to UTF-8
    """
    def __init__(self, f, encoding):
        self.reader = codecs.getreader(encoding)(f)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        return self.reader.next().encode("utf-8")

class UnicodeReader:
    """
    A CSV reader which will iterate over lines in the CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        f = UTF8Recoder(f, encoding)
        self.reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=dialect, **kwds)

    def next(self):
        row = self.reader.next()
        return [unicode(s, "utf-8") for s in row]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

class UnicodeWriter:
    """
    A CSV writer which will write rows to CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow([unicode(s).encode("utf-8") for s in row])
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)

class UnicodeDictWriter(csv.DictWriter, object):
    def __init__(self, f, fieldnames, restval="", extrasaction="raise", dialect="excel", *args, **kwds):
        super(UnicodeDictWriter, self).__init__(f, fieldnames, restval="", extrasaction="raise", dialect="excel", *args, **kwds)
        self.writer = UnicodeWriter(f, dialect, **kwds)
```