# python csv write only certain fieldnames, not all

Tags: python, csv

I must be missing something, but I don't get it. I have a csv, it has 1200 fields. I'm only interested in 30. How do you get that to work? I can read/write the whole shebang, which is ok, but i'd really like to just write out the 30. I have a list of the fieldnames and I'm kinda hacking the header.

How would I translate below to use DictWriter/Reader?

```
for file in glob.glob( os.path.join(raw_path, 'P12*.csv') ):
    fileReader = csv.reader(open(file, 'rb'))
    fileLength = len(file)
    fileGeom = file[fileLength-7:fileLength-4]
    table = TableValues[fileGeom]
    filename = file.split(os.sep)[-1]
    with open(out_path + filename, "w") as fileout:
        for line in fileReader:
            writer = csv.writer(fileout, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            if 'ID' in line:
                outline = line.insert(0,"geometryTable")
            else:
                outline = line.insert(0,table) #"%s,%s\n" % (line, table)
            writer.writerow(line)
```

Answer (score 24):

Here's an example of using `DictWriter` to write out only fields you care about.  I'll leave the porting work to you:

```py
import csv

# Column headers to be included in output.
headers = ['header1', 'header2', 'header4', 'header7']

# Python 3 syntax with the csv module's open requirements.
# The csv module manages newlines itself. newline='' prevents OS text mode translation.
# encoding='utf8' is recommended to handle any Unicode code point in the data.
# Use encoding as needed, but note that the default is OS-dependent so be explicit.
# Use encoding='utf-8-sig' if the UTF-8-encoded CSV will be read by Excel.
with (open('in.csv', 'r', encoding='utf8', newline='') as infile,
      open('out.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as outfile):

    # Always reads all columns.
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)

    # extrasaction='ignore' prevents raising an error if "line" contains
    # columns besides those listed in headers.
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, headers, extrasaction='ignore')

    writer.writeheader()

    for line in reader:
        if line['header4'] != 'data_34':  # optional filtering of rows
            writer.writerow(line)
```

in.csv:

```
header1,header2,header3,header4,header5,header6,header7,header8
data_11,data_12,data_13,data_14,data_15,data_16,data_17,data_18
data_21,data_22,data_23,data_24,data_25,data_26,data_27,data_28
data_31,data_32,data_33,data_34,data_35,data_36,data_37,data_38
data_41,data_42,data_43,data_44,data_45,data_46,data_47,data_48
```

Result (out.csv):

```
header1,header2,header4,header7
data_11,data_12,data_14,data_17
data_21,data_22,data_24,data_27
data_41,data_42,data_44,data_47
```

For Python 2 use the following for opening files and note that the Python 2 `csv` module doesn't handle Unicode well.  Use the 3rd party `unicodecsv` module for Unicode if needed and refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5838817/235698).

```
with open('in.csv', 'rb') as infile, open('out.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
```