# DictWriter can't handle unicode in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary, unicode, utf-8

I want to output a list of dictionaries to a CSV file.

I have the following code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv

items = [{'ởne': 1, 'twở': 2}, {'ởne': 1, 'twở': 2}]
# Note the usage of the "ở" character, aka "\u1edf"

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    fieldnames = items[0].keys() # fetching the keys of the first item as fieldnames
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n')
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerows(items)
```

This fails with the following error :

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u1edf' in position 0: character maps to

How can I get my items to properly output to CSV ?

Comment: specify the correct encoding in `open()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python DictWriter writing UTF-8 encoded CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838605/python-dictwriter-writing-utf-8-encoded-csv-files)

Comment: @Mayhem i've read through that threat, and people are saying that Python 3 should rid us of this issue. I'm using Python 3 and still have it.

Comment: @AChampion, works like a charm, thank you. I tried adding the `encoding="utf-8"` to the DictWriter args, but that didn't work, I didn't think to put them in `open`. Thanks again !